# How to check with cypress that the toggle switch is enabled?

Tags: cypress

i want to add a check that toggle switch is enabled using cypress.

below is the html code,

```
<div>
    <label for="automated">
    <label value="true" class="StyledSwitch-1234">
        <input type="checkbox" id="automated" checked>
        <i class="container"></i>
        <span class="label" data-enabled="on" data-disabled="off"></span>
    </label>
</div>
```

now how do i check label with input child with id "automated" has value "true".

i can access input with id automated like so

```
cy.get('input[id="automated"]')
```

but do i get its parent label and check if its value attribute is true.

could someone help me with this. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For enabled:

```js
cy.get('#automated').should('be.checked')
```

For Not enabled:

```js
cy.get('#automated').should('not.be.checked')
```

Comment: i have input as checked even if toggle switch is set to off

Comment: please add the html of the toggle button when it is off.

Comment: Is this the html for your toggle button. `<label value="true" class="StyledSwitch-1234">`?. If it is, Can you check is the value `false` when the toggle is off.